# How integrate a jar with a custom action in Alfresco

Tags: ant, jar, action, alfresco

I've created a custom action with as a eclipse project. I packaged it in a jar and I put it in: alfresco-3.4.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib

I started Alfresco and I created a rule with my custom action. When a file is created in this folder then the rule is triggered.

But when I create a file, the unique available type is "content", my custom content types don't show in select list. My problem is I need these custom types.

I have tested starting Alfresco without my jar and all types are availables.

My project structure is wrong?:

```
 src.main.java
 -executer
   ·UrlActionExecuter.java
   ·UrlActionHandler.java
 src.main.resources
 -alfresco.extension
   ·url-actions-context.xml
   ·web-client-config-custom.xml
   ·webclient.properties
 src.main.webapp
  -jsp.actions
   ·url-action-executer.jsp
```

or build.xml?:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="Action Url" default="package" basedir=".">

    <property name="project.dir" value="."/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="${project.dir}/build"/>
    <property name="package.file" value="${build.dir}/Action-url.jar"/>

    <path id="class.path">
        <dirset dir="${build.dir}" />
        <fileset dir="../../lib/server" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <javac classpathref="class.path" srcdir="${project.dir}/src" destdir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="package" >
        <jar destfile="${package.file}">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}"/>
        </jar>
    </target>

</project>
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Not sure exactly what you problem is. What does your action do? Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your custom types should described in the model file and then you should import your model to the alfresco, for example:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>

<beans>
    <bean id="custom_dictionaryBootstrap"
        parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
        <property name="models">
            <list>
                <value>alfresco/module/mymodule/model/mymodel.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="labels">
            <list>
                <value>alfresco/module/mymodule/messages/system</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```